# Laravel : Passing value from view to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**My View:**

```
                        <table border="1" style="text-align: left;">

                        <td>
                            <b>Firstname</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Actions</b>
                        </td>

                        @foreach($Newslist as $News)
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                         {{ $News->lastname }}   
                        </td>
                        <td>
                         <a href="/NewsEdit/{{$News->id}}/EditForm"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></a>  
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach

                </table>
```

**My routes/web.php:**

```
Route::Post('NewsEdit/{{$News->id}}/EditForm','NewsControllere@EditForm');
```

**My Controller.php:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Newsmodel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewsControllere extends Controller
{
    public function EditForm($NewsId)
    {   dd(request()->all());
        echo "deepakkeynes";exit();
        //$Newsmodel = Newsmodel::find($NewsId);

        //return view('/News')->with('News',$Newsmodel);
    }
}
```

While clicking the edit button in the view, the following result is obtained:
**Result:**  404 page
**Expected Result:** The Id of the edit button along with the echo value!

Can anyone help me out? I am a newbie in laravel..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this LaraCast tutorial on [Route Model Binding](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/9).  This explains the [underlying documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-model-binding) well.

**Essentially:**

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('NewsEdit/{news}/EditForm','NewsControllere@EditForm');
```

newsController.php:

```
public function EditForm(Newsmodel $news)
    {  
        return view('/News')->with('News',$news);
    }
```

Comment: Error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: @DeepakKeynes - sorry - hadn't noticed that you were using POST in your original question - see edit

Comment: The error got cleared after I put 'get' instead of 'post'. Thanks for the timely help

Comment: Rory, Help me in this question also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219290/laravel-showing-null-value-after-form-submit