# Laravel showing null value after form submit

Tags: php, laravel

**My View:**

```
<form action="/AddJuiceForm" method="POST">
    @csrf;
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="FruitName">Fruit Name : </label>
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter the Fruit Name"
            name="fruitname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="JuiceName">Juice Name : </label>
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter the Juice Name"
            name="juicename">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**My Routes/web.php:**

```
Route::post('AddJuiceForm','JuiceController@insertjuice ');
```

**My Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\JuiceModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JuiceController extends Controller
{
    public function insertjuice()
    {
        dd(request()->all);
    }
}
```

Result: I am getting 'null' as output

Help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `all()` is a method, not a property. So it should be `request()->all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object into the `insertjuice` method and then call the `all()` **method** on the variable within your `JuiceController` class:

```
public function insertjuice(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: I also gave dd(request()->all()); by without passing any arguments in the insertjuice() and that also worked. But I dont know what is the difference between these two..

Comment: Yep that will work too.  The error was you were looking for a property vs using the method for `all`.  You can do either requests as you note, both are fine.  I like to inject it into the method for clarity, as this is the way the docs do it, but both are totally good!